# Variable importance of Numerical features in Classification Model - Random Forest Classifier

Tags: random-forest, feature-engineering, machine-learning-model, feature-scaling

I have few numeric features in my model. Out of 25 features, I have 7-8 numeric features in my model. 
One thing I observed is model gives more weightage to numerical feature compare to categorical features. 
Is it always behave the same way or it is because of the features?

Should I convert those numeric features into  categorical?